# Justify inline form with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering if there is any way to justify an inline form with bootstrap? I have a form with several rows of controls (form-groups) and want them all to end at the same place regardless of how many controls are in each row. Is there a way to do this?

The form:

```
     <div class="panel panel-body" data-bind="foreach: Contract">
        <div class="form-inline panel">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">First Name</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" title="First Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Last Name</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" title="Last Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm panel">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Address</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" title="Address" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline panel">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">City</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" title="City" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">State</span>
                <select placeholder="State" title="State" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Zip</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" title="Zip Code" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm panel">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Total $</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" title="Total">
            <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7abpdxpb/2/

Here is an updated fiddle with an ugly way to do it via % widths: https://jsfiddle.net/7abpdxpb/3/

I would really rather not do it this way because it stretches out the input's labels and also I'm not sure how this would react to re-sizing and all that...

Comment: Do you mean you want all the `span` elements the same width? It's not clear? Do you have an image of the intended result(s).

Comment: On the left side they are all aligned... I want them all aligned on the right side as well. That is what "justified" means.

Comment: Yes...but "what" is supposed to be aligned. When I open the fiddle they're all the same 100% width?

Comment: Each row - I want each row's controls to start and end at the same place...  last name and zip code would end where address and total do.

Comment: Oooo...that might take some restructuring...or swapping out some classes perhaps with javascript.

Comment: I know there is a way to do it with navigation stuff - .nav-justified - was just curious if there was some built-in bootstrap thing to do it with form-groups like it is with nav stuff.

Comment: A simple, but not so beautiful, way would be to make `input-group`'s width 100% and then change the `panel`'s width in what suits you. This would not require any restructuring

Comment: I'll check the docs...I'm sure this is covered somewhere.

Comment: Why not use the Bootstrap grid columns instead of `form-inline` since you have multiple rows of inputs? That would be the usual way to create a justified form http://codeply.com/go/m99hVPtb8K

Comment: @Skelly - This works best - no label stretching! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap column for the same:

```
<div class="panel panel-body" data-bind="foreach: Contract">
    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" title="First Name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Last Name</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" title="Last Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm panel">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Address</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" title="Address" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-inline panel">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">City</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" title="City" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">State</span>
                    <select placeholder="State" title="State" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline panel">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Zip</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" title="Zip Code" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm panel">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Total $</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" title="Total">
                <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/2jo069mt/21/

Comment: I was playing with columns, but I read somewhere not to mix form stuff with column stuff or something like that.... I still don't like the area for the labels being stretched, but this is as close as it can probably get to what I was looking for. Thanks!